# Laravel Password resets for multiple auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

i have a second auth for companies which is working. But the only thing i have a problem with is sending the password token email for companies. It always sends the email from users.

That´s my app/config/auth.php

If i change on defaults the passwords value to companies it works, but only for companies then and not for users.

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'company' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'companies',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'companies' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Company::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'companies' => [
        'provider' => 'companies',
        'email' => 'business.auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'company_password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],

];
```

Maybe that´s a simple error.. I hope somebody can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Follow these steps, http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/ and I've also mentioned my github link to which Multi auth implemented with password reset option. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 8):

On your PasswordResetLinkController, replace

`Password::sendResetLink( ...`

with

`Password::broker('companies')->sendResetLink( ...`

On the NewPasswordController, replace

`Password::reset( ...`

with

`Password::broker('companies')->reset( ...`